# JavaScript default constructor| array | loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, constructor

I need to make a script but I have no idea how to complete it.
This is what I have to do:

(1) Write a class Boxes. this class has a default constructor and an empty array named boxes.

further has this class 3 methods:

1) insert add method to put Box into the boxes-array.
2) insert method size to get the actual size of the array.
3) insert toString method which give color and volume back in one string.

(2) continue in the init function:

2.3 turn a loop around every object from the array *objects* to add it to the array boxes

2.4 make a toString method to give back every object from your array in one HTML P-tag.

I hope this makes sense to you guys and it would be a big help if somebody could help me!

A big thanks in advance!

Update: I have edited the code to what I have now.

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
    // (2.1)
    let object1 = new Box(20, 8, 3, "white");
    let object2 = new Box(30, 20, 10, "Brown");
    let object3 = new Box(50, 40, 20);
    // (2.2)
    let boxes = new Boxes();
    // (2.3)
    boxes.push(object1);
    boxes.push(object2);
    boxes.push(object3);
    // 2.4
    var str=""
    for (let i = 0 ; i < boxes.size() ; i++){
        str += "<p>"+boxes.toString(i)+"<p>"
    }

}

class Box {
    constructor(length, width, height, color = "blue") {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.heigt = height;
        this.color = color;
    }

    volume() {
        return this.length * this.width * this.height;
    }

    toString() {   // String templates
        return `Volume: ${this.volume()} --- Kleur: ${this.color}`;
    }
}

// (1) class Boxes
class Boxes {
    constructor(){
        this.boxes = [];
    }

    add(Box){
        this.boxes.push(Box);
    }

    size(){
        return this.boxes.length;
    }

    toString(i){
        this.boxes[i].toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Soooo is this a school assignment?

Comment: You have to show what you have tried. What part are you having difficulty with? Just copying someone else's solution won't help you nearly as much.

Comment: I've got javascript exam tommorow. and i suppose this is a reference to what i will get. I've already tried putting up a default constructor using constructor() {} and that's as far as i've gotten :)

Comment: Also, I am confused as to why you have a class for your boxes array, just make a new array saying `var boxes = [];`. Then for (2.3) you can use `.push()` to add the box to the array

Comment: More of a reason for you to try it on your own and for no one else to write anything until you ask a specific question.

Comment: @mhodges Using a class to represent a collection of something is pretty common

Comment: And for (2.4) you can use a number of different methods to create an html string from an array of objects (i.e. `.forEach()`, `.reduce()`)

Comment: hat is frustrating is that wehave to do this without any reference. it's pretty imossible when 6 weeks ago you never heard of anything about java or javascript

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah, I mean I guess if you were wanting to do any sort of complex data structures, or add prototype methods it makes sense. I'm still a big believer that adding a formal class to JavaScript in ES6 was a poor choice, though.

Comment: @mhodges But you shouldn't preach about that to someone who's doing a homework on JavaScript OO ;)

Comment: @JuanMendes Fight the power! ;)

Comment: i'll edit it a bit and see if it's correct

Comment: @ThomasP I gave you some pointers, scattered amongst the comments. Look into `.push()` for (2.3) and `.forEach()` or `.reduce()` for (2.4)

Comment: i've edited a bit really fast and wrote down my first thoughts. so if it really makes no sense just tell me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what's 3) means so I would assume that you want to get the box color and volume given the index (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
class Boxes{
  //init property called boxes to an empty array when creating Boxes object
  constructor(){
    this.boxes = [];
  }
  //return the length of the boxes
  size(){
    return this.boxes.length;
  }
  //add a box by pushing it to the array
  add(box){
   this.boxes.push(box);
  }
  //print the volume and color of a box given the index
  toString(i){
   this.boxes[i].toString();
  }
}
```

for number 2:

```
//2.3
//do you have to push the objects to object?
//use this if you don't have to
boxes.push(object1);
boxes.push(object2);
boxes.push(object3);
//use this if you pushed your objects into an array called object
objects.forEach(function(singleObject){
  boxes.push(singleObject);
});

//2.4
//Iterate every object in boxes and print out their volume and color
//Do you have to create a P tag or just wrapped the string with <p></p>?
//This answer assumes that you just wrap it with <p></p>. Correct me if I'm wrong
var str = "";
//option 1 Using foreach loop
boxes.boxes.forEach((singleBox){
  str += "<p>"+singleBox.toString()+"</p>";
});
//option 2 Using for loop
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++){
   str += "<p>"+boxes.toString(i)+"</p>";
}
//now str contains every object's color and volume wrapped in P tag
```

I would recommend you to go through this course https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript

Comment: thanks it's not quite correct but it's definitely a good help and direction were I need to go. to be honest i find the questions given by my teacher quite weird and unlogical. but a really big thanks though

Comment: Hi @ThomasP the process of learning involves asking questions.. So if you don't understand anything that your teacher gave you, you should ask! It's quite logical to give an assignment like this..